# Why does the output voltage of a boost converter depend on current only in DCM, not CCM?

Tags: circuit-analysis, circuit-design, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, dc-dc-converter

I read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boost_converter) and understood all the derivations for the output voltage and average inductor current for the boost converter in CCM and DCM operation. However, it's not intuitively clear to me why DCM output voltage depends on the load but CCM does not.

I can easily see that from the output voltage expression but what I'm looking for is the intuitive explanation for this.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

**CCM** has just two phases; charge and transfer. Load current changes are accommodated by the whole of the inductor current waveform rising or falling: -

[image]

I'll paraphrase something important from above:

$$\color{blue}{\text{Load changes cause the whole of the inductor current waveform to rise or fall}}$$

This means that with perfect switching semiconductors (MOSFET and diode), the output voltage is related only to input voltage and duty cycle.

**DCM** has three distinct phases per switching cycle; charge, transfer and hold. The length of the hold phase accommodates variations in load current: -

[image]

Energy transfer can only be modified by the duty cycle so, if the load requires less energy (i.e. the load resistance has become higher in value), then, in DCM, if D remains constant, the same energy is delivered to a higher resistance load and, output voltage **has to rise**.

Images from [my crappy website](http://www.stades.co.uk/Boost%20converter/Boost%20calculator.html).

**CCM voltage transfer formula**

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{1}{1-D}$$

**DCM voltage transfer formula**

$$\dfrac{V_{OUT}}{V_{IN}} = \dfrac{1}{2}+ \sqrt{\dfrac{1}{4}+\dfrac{D^2\cdot R_{LOAD}}{2\cdot L\cdot F_{SW}}}$$

Answer (score 3):

What you need to remember about an inductor is that the net current change should be zero.

The change in the inductor current, Δi, is determined by the frequency and input voltage only (assuming the output voltage is kept constant via feedback).

[image]

Image Source: Andy's answer.

Look at the blue lines. As you can see, the current ramps down to the value that it starts to ramp up at. Even if the duration of charge and transfer periods are not equal the current returns to the same value. If you change **the load only** (i.e. keeping the input voltage constant), the whole curve will move up or down accordingly because **the mid-point of the ramp up and down section is the DC load current**. And the net change remains zero, because the inductor current still moves Δi and -Δi due to the un-changed input voltage. Therefore the inductor current-voltage equation holds and the load resistance has no effect here.

Unless the current hits zero (imagine the blue line is at zero), the waveform will remain and the only thing that matters is the "on" time (i.e. charging time). So the output will only depend on the timing which is determined by the frequency and input and output voltages (for a closed loop system).

When the current hits zero and remains at zero for a non-zero duration (i.e. hold) then things start to change. This is when the DCM starts. The hold duration completely depends on the load because, for example, as the load increases the waveform will move down further so the hold time will increase further. Still the net current change for the inductor is zero but the current **waits** for start to ramp up again.

[image]

Image Source: Andy's answer.

Sorry Andy, I had to use your images.

Comment: You are forgiven lol +1

Comment: Thanks @Andyaka . I knew you are a saint :)

Comment: @RohatKılıç I have a slight confusion. I have a slight confusion. Why  is the average voltage in CCM zero. I mean if the duty cycle is 70 percent then it means the rate of charge must be less than that of discharge. The inductor should discharge faster. We made an assumption that this discharge should be done to make the current constant. But this  is just an assumption and it is  possible that inductor doesnt discharge fully and next charging cycle comes. I know I am wrong but am not getting how...Kindly help me in this..

Comment: @kam1212 `Why is the average voltage in CCM zero.` which voltage? Inductor's voltage? Or something else?

Comment: @RohatKılıç Inductor voltage.

Comment: @kam1212 this is not a thing that I can explain in a comment box. Please do some research on "volt-seconds balance". This is basically the flux balance of the magnetic core. The net flux change over a period should be zero. Otherwise the core will saturate after some time. As you study, you'll see that the net voltage over a period should be zero.